# JSON schema validation in marklogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, jsonschema, marklogic-9, json-schema-validator

I was trying to validate simple JSON document against a JSON schema in query console having a query type "javascript" but i am getting an error.

Schema validation code :-

```
xdmp.jsonValidateNode(
      { "count": 3, "items": [12] }, 
      {
        "properties": {
           "count": { "type":"integer", "minimum":0 },
           "items": { "type":"array", "items": {"type":"string", "minLength":1 } }
         }
      })
```

Error :-

> [javascript] JS-JAVASCRIPT: xdmp.jsonValidateNode( -- Error running
> JavaScript request: TypeError: xdmp.jsonValidateNode is not a function
> Stack Trace At line 1 column 5: In xdmp.jsonValidateNode(
>
> 1. xdmp.jsonValidateNode(
> 2. { "count": 3, "items": [12] },

This is marklogic supported function. How it is throwing not a fnction error.

Also, is there any other way to validate json document against json schema in marklogic ?

Comment: Is this all your code? Please consider providing a jsfiddle showing your error. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What version of MarkLogic are you running exactly? Top-left in Admin UI should tell..

Comment: I am using ML 9.0-6.2

Answer (score 3):

[xdmp.jsonValidateNode()](http://docs.marklogic.com/9.0/xdmp.jsonValidateNode) is a newer function. You will need to upgrade to a later 9.0 release.

Executing your snippet in 9.0-9.1 works and returns a validation error:

> [javascript] XDMP-JSVALIDATEINVTYPE: xdmp.jsonValidateNode( -- Invalid node type: Expected node of type text, found number at NumberNode(12) using schema ""

I recommend upgrading to the [latest 9.0 release](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/9.0) (currently 9.0-11) or [MarkLogic 10](https://developer.marklogic.com/products/marklogic-server/10.0)

Comment: Thanks Mads for quick help. In that case, can you please suggest me how to do schema validation for JSON document in ML 9.0-6.2 as this is the version we are currently using in production.